# Zoom Image is not working in some devices

Tags: android, imageview, pinchzoom

I used https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView library for zooming images and Picasso and Glide for image getting, but issue is there are many glitches I found on pinch to zoom image.
After that I tried many other libraries aswell but all library output are same,
So my question is how can I load and show big images in low end android devices?

I used Picasso or Glide for get Image

`Picasso.get().load(imageUrl).memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE).into(imageview);`